# Alternative to 'CopyTextReport' command in OxyPlot when it is Obsolete

Tags: wpf, oxyplot

I've been using OxyPlot (2.0.0) to generate plots in my application, and I previously used the 'CopyTextReport' command to copy text-based reports from the plot. However, it seems that this command is no longer available in my current version of OxyPlot 2.1.2.

Have any of you encountered this issue, and if so, how did you address it?
Are there any alternative methods or commands that can be used to achieve the same result of copying text-based reports from an OxyPlot plot?

If possible, please provide code examples or explanations of how to implement the alternative solution in your answer.

Additionally, if you know which OxyPlot version introduced this change, or if there is an official announcement regarding this, please share that information as well.

I have searched on the official OxyPlot website (https://oxyplot.github.io/) for this but did not find any relevant information. It seems that a custom solution using C# code is needed.

Comment: As per the change log https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md the Copy to text report Ctrl+Alt+R is removed. But not provided any alternative